# Cannot open SonarQube in web-browser

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to integrate SonarQube and Jenkins, for which I have installed both these tools on a remote `Vagrant VM` (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).
Everything is working fine, the build is successful when I run the SonarQube analysis in Jenkins, but I am not able to open the Sonar dashboard at `http://<myipaddress>:port` from my windows (local) machine.
 When the build is successful in Jenkins, it gives me a URL so as to browse the Analysis report but this URL gives me `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

Options I have tried so far:

1. Tried disabling Ubuntu firewall
2. When I perform tracert from Windows, it gives me 'Destination host unreachable'.
3. When I try pinging my remote machine from Windows machine, it gives me request timed out error.
4. Tried checking sonarqube logs which do not show any error.

I tried other options as well but none seems to work. It will be of great help if anyone can guide me through this. I am not quite able to figure out how to open SonarQube's dashboard in my local machine through a web browser, while it has been installed at a remote machine.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is evident from your explanation, remote machine in which SonarQube installed is not accessible from your machine.

Comment: Check if you can open the website on the local machine. If the succeeds you have a firewall problem.

Comment: Maybe you need to setup reverse-proxy for the server. Or, enable the port where sonar is running to be accessible from outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the firewall allows the port of SonarQube to be accessible from other networks.

Run the following command to check if the SonarQube port is open or not:

`sudo ufw status verbose`

If your firewall is disabled this command will give you the following output:

`Status: inactive`

In this case enable your firewall by running `sudo ufw enable` and then again run

`sudo ufw status verbose`

It will give you an output like the following:

[image]

If the output doesn't show SonarQube port then enable its port by using the following command:

`sudo ufw allow <SONAR_PORT>/tcp`

This will allow your SonarQube port to be accessible.

Comment: Thanks for your input but the port which SonarQube is using is already in the firewall list. The port is accessible, but the IP address of my remote machine is not(from local machine). I tried modifying the /hosts file in my remote machine to resolve the problem, but I am still not able to access SonarQube's dashboard on the browser.

Comment: @HarneetKaur, then please enable the IP address of your local machine to connect to the remote machine by running the following command: `sudo ufw allow from <LOCAL_MACHINE_IP>`

Comment: Turned out that the firewall allowed the port 9000 for the guest VM but it was not the case for the host server. I had to contact the server administrator as I did not have permissions to enable the port on the host server. Everything is working now. Thanks!